# Social Network SQL statement for posts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been working on a Social Network to further my knowledge with PHP, however I have come to the point where I will be pulling posts from he database depending on who the user is "friends" with.

My database structure for friends is as follows:

```
USER_A | USER_B | CREATED_AT | IS_BLOCKED
```

And then for the posts:

```
USER | UPDATE | STATUS
```

So, I want to show posts selected from my post table if the user logged in is friends with the user who posted it.

So, basically, wondering if anyone has any suggestions. It won't be anymore complicated than that, not interested in getting friends of friends or anything like that. So, just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with this one.

I read it would require JOINs and such, however I have never really stepped into that side of SQL so therefore would have no idea what I would be doing with it, so links to relevant questions and articles on that, if required, would be appreciated.

Thanks

(I am essentially looking for help with the SQL statement, not with the PHP.)

**Update #1:**

I have got the newsfeed working, now I need to be able to join a statement to get the users names to be displayed. My current status is on this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b07793/1/0

*Before anyone goes crazy about storing passwords in plaintext, this is not a public system, it is purely for me to test, and hashing passwords for a non-public script that will only ever be used by me with fake passwords is hardly a security risk, it just makes debugging a pain.*

Comment: Making a http://sqlfiddle.com/ may make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: What represent User_B in the friends table ?

Comment: @aleroot User_B is the user the person is friends with / requested to be friends with, once the request is confirmed. At the moment, it is one-way meaning per every friendship, one database record.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b07793/2  -- this will retrieve the name. Join on al_users.id instead of forename.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work :

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
JOIN friends ON posts.user = friends.user_b
WHERE user_a = 'someuser'
```

In this statement we are JOINING to tables : posts and friends, based on the value of two column, we are putting in relation the column user of the post table with the column user_b of the friends table, in this way we will obtain a result set with only the value of the two table where the two columns in relation are equal ...

Comment: Can you explain what is actually happening in the statement? Whilst it may work, it is not helpful for when I come to doing this again. I don't want to be spoonfed answers, rather educated on what is going on. Cheers

Comment: @JakeBall: If you don't want to be spoonfed read some tutorials. This is a questions and answers site, not an online training course. Especially about the basics of SQL statements you will find *tons* of tutorials online.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I wasn't looking for an online training course either,  was simply asking if he could explain what was going on. Its hardly helpful, it is essentially just everything done for me without any explanation as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the db schema you described, this will bring you all posts that have been written by a user that is friends with the logged in user.

```
 SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.user IN (SELECT user_b FROM friendships WHERE user_a=$logged_in_user)
```

The query is pretty simple. You get all the rows from table `posts` that the creator of that post has a line in your `friendships` table as user_b while user_a is set to be the logged in user.

Comment: You'd have to use an `OR` in the nested query, as `user_a` and `user_b` could be the logged in user or the user to view.

Comment: @Oshawott I think this really depends if he has a symmetric or asymmetric social network. Also, even if it is symmetric, I would recommend adding two lines to the friendships table, instead of doing a more complex query, because news-feed queries tend to become the bottleneck.

Comment: He confirmed it's one record per friendship in comments earlier: "@ aleroot User_B is the user the person is friends with / requested to be friends with, once the request is confirmed. At the moment, it is one-way meaning per every friendship, one database record." -- as to whether doubling the size of the db or doubling the complexity of this query is more important, depends on metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a few things, if they're not correct you'll have to modify this stuff but if I'm right, these operations won't need any `JOIN`s:

1. `$userSession` variable contains the user who's logged in's ID.
2. `$userToView` variable contains the user who he's trying to view's ID.
3. Your database structure will only have one entry for the two users who are friends, so we have to check both combinations.

To determine if the user is a friend:

```
SELECT user_a, user_b FROM friends
WHERE (user_a = $userSession AND user_b = $userToView)
OR (user_a = $userToView AND user_b = $userSession)
LIMIT 1;
```

Then you'd use an `if` statement in PHP (it's usually better to keep business logic in the application, rather than in the database), if it's true return the posts.

```
$results = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_row();
if($results) {
    ... return posts ...
} else {
    echo 'Not friends';
}
```

That would be a query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE user = $userToView;
```

You will need to read up about [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (do not use mysql plugin, it's deprecated) and about [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and how to prevent them. It may sound like a hassle, but it's far less daunting to understand this stuff than to deal with the fallout if you don't.

Comment: Thanks, I have already moved over to PDO. Did it a few months back and it was a truly great move, much more can be done with it and it s just infinitely better than the MySQL_* functions, thanks for example SQL syntax! I didn't think it would be that simple, now if I was to grab USER_B's information within the same statement, would that require a join? Since I will be fetching data from another table?

Comment: No problem, hope it helps.

Comment: @JakeBall - If you wanted to get data from 2 tables at the same time (in a single query), that would require a `JOIN`. If, for example, you had the user's `id` as primary key in `posts` and `users`, but you needed their `real_name` from `users` table, and `post` from `posts` table, you would use a `JOIN`.

Comment: So, will this normally require two queries of the database then? If I had multiple posts on one page I would be looking at quite a few queries, would there be no other way of doing this to streamline this?

Comment: @JakeBall - This would use two queries total, not two queries per post. Once you know they are friends, you could use the `fetch_assoc()` function to return every post by `$userToView` in an associative array.

Comment: of course, completely skipped my mind that I wasn't fetching more data. Thank you for that, helps a lot I will take it into account and try it out

Comment: Hey @oshawott, that works pretty nicely, however I have tried to modify the statement to display a news-feed sort of thing, where all posts from user_a friends will be displayed, got that working, but now I am trying to join my users table to get the persons information, basic, such as first and last name. Statement I used, which yields no results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b07793/1/0